# ¿Cómo unir dos dataframe de acuerdo a la fecha?

Tags: r, date, datatable

Dado el siguiente ejemplo ejemplo:

df1 (La fecha está como d,m,Y, están separados por / y los datos de fecha están como "FACTOR")

```
Fecha-------------VariableX------------- VariableY
-------------------------

01/01/2000---------------------20--------------------------------32

02/01/2000---------------------35--------------------------------46

03/01/2000---------------------38 -------------------------------44
```

df2 (La fecha está como Y,m,d, separados por - y también son datos de tipo "FACTOR"

```
Fecha-------------VariableA------------- VariableB
--------------------------------------------------

2000-02-01----------------------35---------------------------------28

2000-04-05----------------------42---------------------------------37

2000-08-31----------------------24---------------------------------32
```

Lo que quiero es unir los ficheros por la fecha, para que, por ejemplo, no hayan datos de la variable X del df1 fuera de las fechas de registro de la variableB del df2.

Estoy intentando algo así, usando el paquete data.table

```
setkv(df2, c("fecha","VariableX"))
Result<-subset(def2, fecha >= min(df1$fecha) & fecha<= max(df1$fecha))
```

Como era de esperarse, al ejecutar el comando me sale error por que los formatos de fechas no coinciden y no están en formato numérico. Pienso que la manera de convertirlos a número es con `as.numeric(df1$fecha)`, pero antes de hacer eso, debería poner los datos de fecha de los df de la misma manera: o todos d,m,Y, o todos Y,m,d, pero no tengo ni idea de cómo hacerlo. Espero que me hayan entendido.

Answer (score 1):

En primer lugar armamos un ejemplo reproducible de tus datos, he agregado una nueva observación en `df1` ya que el filtro que deseas aplicar no retornaría ninguna fila

```
df1 <- data.frame(Fecha = c('01/01/2000', '02/01/2000', '03/01/2000', '05/04/2000'),
      VariableX  = c(20, 35, 38, 1),
      VariableY = c(32, 46, 44, 2)
)

df2 <- data.frame(Fecha = c('2000-02-01', '2000-04-05', '2000-08-31'),
                  VariableA  = c(35, 42,24),
                  VariableB = c(28, 37, 32)
)
```

#### Factores

Este tipo de dato es ampliamente usado en R y muy útil, pero nos obliga a convertirlo cada vez que necesitemos hacer alguna comparación. La conversión natural de un `factor` es a un `character` por medio de `as.character()`. Para convertir el formato de fecha de uno de los dataframes, hay que simplemente recortar cada parte y reubicarla. Para poder comparar correctamente las fechas como caracteres es imprescindible usar el formato `YYYY-MM-DD`, sino deberíamos convertir las columnas a un tipo de dato fecha.

```
df1$Fecha <- paste(substr(as.character(df1$Fecha),7,10), 
                   substr(as.character(df1$Fecha),4,5),
                   substr(as.character(df1$Fecha),1,2),
                   sep = '-')

# Dejamos la columna como factor como es originalmente
df1$Fecha <- as.factor(df1$Fecha)
```

La comparación que quieres hacer ahora es posible:

```
df2[as.character(df2$Fecha) >= min(as.character(df1$Fecha)) & as.character(df2$Fecha) <= max(as.character(df1$Fecha)),]
```

Mucho más sencillo, una vez formateada la fecha, es trabajarla directamente como `Date`:

```
df1$Fecha <- as.Date(df1$Fecha)
df2$Fecha <- as.Date(df2$Fecha)

df2[df2$Fecha >= min(df1$Fecha) & df2$Fecha <= max(df1$Fecha),]
```

Comment: Genial! @Patricio Moracho nuevamente mil gracias. Hasta la próxima pregunta :)